# How to set property to all controls on a UserForm?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I need to set a property `.Value` & `ForeColor` to all controls on a UserForm from a macro outside the UserForm.

The userform is shown as `vbModeless`.

The below code without `On Error Resume Next` is producing

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

At `ctrl.Value = False` &  `ctrl.ForeColor = vbBlack`.

If I use the not recommended `On Error Resume Next`, then the code works.

```vb
Sub Clear_All_Filter()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim ctrl As control
    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
        ctrl.Value = False
        ctrl.ForeColor = vbBlack
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Well it clear. One of your controls doesn't one of those properties. I'm not sure on your comments about `On Error Resume Next` - are you saying you don't check return values for errors?.

Comment: @Lundt , thanks I found that the userform contains a Label, after I removed it then it works without using `On Error Resume Next` .you can post as answer if you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have a label-control that doesn't support `value`.
Check for the type of the control within your loop:

```vb
Sub Clear_All_Filter()
   
    Dim ctrl As Control
      For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) <> "Label" Then
            ctrl.Value = False
            ctrl.ForeColor = vbBlack
        End If
      Next
End Sub
```